# How would I get the top role of a bot(client) in discordpy

Tags: python, discord, bots, roles

So right now my setup is

```
       if memb.id != 'EzLife#9391' and memb.id != message.guild.owner.id and memb.top_role < client.top_role:
```

but the issue is that the client is a bot and the bot has no top role. I tried to get the member of the bot by doing client.me.top_role but I dont get any top role. any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, in the latest version of discord.py, there is no `client.me`
Here's something you can do though (using `discord.ext's commands`):

```py
member = ctx.guild.get_member(client.user.id)
top_role = member.top_role
```

`top_role` will return `discord.Role`, so you can do `top_role.name`, `top_role.id`, etc.

You can check out the documentation here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.top_role

You can also join the discordpy discord for more help: https://discord.com/invite/r3sSKJJ